Not able to get all picklist values from a particular recordtype using uiObjectInfoApi
import CASE_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Case";
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues,getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
export default class OfficialLanguages extends LightningElement { 
    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: "012D50000002gRgIAI",})
        picklistInfo({data,error}){
        if (data) {
            console.log('position  picklistInfo data 7 = ',data);
            let field = data.picklistFieldValues;
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log('position error ',error);
        }
    };
}


Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. We will need more information in order for us to help you. What are you getting for the output, and what are you expecting? Please [edit] your question to include more information so we can help you.


Make sure that the recordTypeId you are using is correct.
Make sure that the fields you are trying to access have the appropriate field-level security settings for the user's profile.

